# Efficient way for calculating power of signal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, multidimensional-array, signal-processing

I have `n_sample` brain signals and I want to compute the power for each sample.

Here is my code:

```
def return_power_of_signal(input_signal):
    #The power of a signal is the sum of the absolute squares of its time-domain samples divided 
    #by the signal length, or, equivalently, the square of its RMS level.
    #my approach
    
    #input: np.array of (n_sample, time_length)
    
    n_sample = input_signal.shape[0]
    n_time = input_signal.shape[1]
    
    results_array = np.empty((n_sample, 1))
    
    for i in range(n_sample):
        sum_sample = 0
        for j in range(n_time):
            sum_sample += input_signal[i, j]*input_signal[i, j]
        sum_sample = sum_sample/n_time
        results_array[i] = sum_sample
    
    return results_array
```

However, I wonder can there be any better way (more efficient/less coding?) way of calculating this?

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of `input_signal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.abs(input_signal)**2, this gets the absolute value and then the square operator obtains the magnitude.